# Tips on Distributed Monitoring Software?

Tags: server, network-programming, monitoring, distributed

we need to monitor computers in different places around the country. They are running software from us in different commercial stores. I am talking about VR-Unity applications and Chrome-Applications.

We need to monitor if they are on, running the software, the right fame rate, ideally temperature of the GPU, CPU. Stuff like that. Any tips on software?

Thank, you!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good use-case for [SNMPv3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol). The SNMP agent will be running on the hosts ([SNMPd](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/man/snmpd.html) is a linux agent). The agent will report certain metrics to an SNMP Managers. The metrics reported are determined by MiB's and the parameters you mentioned are already in most default MiBs for OSs. The SNMP Manager will be at your NetOps Server and can record/analyze/visualize what you want to see. [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/) (Free) and [Solar Winds](http://www.solarwinds.com/) (Pay) are two common SNMP Manager programs.

Additionally, by using SNMP you can easily incorporate Networking devices that are also being used in remote infrastructures.